# smart way to read multiple variables from textfile in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to load multiple vectors and matrices (for numpy) that are stored in a single text file.
The file looks like this:

```
%VectorA
1 2 3 4
%MatrixA
1 2 3
4 5 6
%VectorB
3 4 5 6 7
```

The ideal solution would be to have a dictionary object like:

```
{'VectorB': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'VectorA': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'MatrixA':[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]}
```

The order of the variables can be assumed as fixed. So, a list of the numpy arrays in the order of appearance in the text file would also be okay.

Comment: Can you still change the format in your text files or is this something you have to live with?

Comment: it flexible as long as one knows which data is where. but the values should be space separated.

Comment: Why do you need to keep the values space separated? I mean are there some special reasons why you couldn't use `numpy.load` and `numpy.save`?

Comment: I actually meant "white space" separated. :) Because I do copy&paste these from the console output of an existing c++ application, and I cant modify the the vector and matrix output. Otherwise I would probably have used the `pickle` module if it was from python to python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
mytext='''%VectorA
1 2 3 4
%MatrixA
1 2 3
4 5 6
%VectorB
3 4 5 6 7'''

myfile=StringIO(mytext)
mydict={}
for x in myfile.readlines():
    if x.startswith('%'):
        mydict.setdefault(x.strip('%').strip(),[])
        lastkey=x.strip('%').strip()
    else:
        mydict[lastkey].append([int(x1) for x1 in x.split(' ')])
```

above gives `mydict` as:

```
{'MatrixA': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
 'VectorA': [[1, 2, 3, 4]],
 'VectorB': [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]}
```